# How can I export the "Enable for OG Menus" content type option status in a feature?

Tags: organic-groups, features, strongarm

How can I export the "Enable for OG Menus" content type option status in a feature?

I have successfully exported several different OG content types into their own feature. All my settings have exported, except for the "Enable for OG Menus" option. I have a couple types where that option is enabled, and I have og_menu as a dependency. But when I enable the content type feature on a new Drupal instance, that option remains in it's default unchecked state.

I have Drupal 7.39, Features 7.x-2.6, OG Menu 7.x-3.0, and Strongarm 7.x-2.x-dev installed. As well as their dependencies.

Is there a Strongarm variable I'm missing? I don't see any in the list that look like they come from OG Menu.

I have Googled, didn't find anything relevant with the search terms I tried.

I searched the issue queues of Features, OG Menu, and Strongarm to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a Strongarm variable.

Strongarm lists:

- og_menu_assignment
- og_menu_block_links
- og_menu_context_limit
- og_menu_create_by_default
- og_menu_enable_page
- og_menu_enable_section
- og_menu_hide_create_option
- og_menu_hide_help
- og_menu_max_menus_per_group
- og_menu_show_blocks
- og_menu_show_nodetype

The variables I needed were:

- og_menu_enable_page
- og_menu_enable_section

og_menu appears to create a variable per content type you want to use it on. In my case I had two content types, page and section. Once I added those variables to my feature, it successfully exported the setting.